# Ubuntu 20.04 and 21.04: second cursor stuck on the screen 150% fractional scaling on a 1440p monitor after login (XOrg)

Tags: xorg, amdgpu, scaling, hdpi

EDIT: example https://i.stack.imgur.com/6W70m.jpg

If "fractional scaling" is set to 150%, then after login there is a second cursor stuck on the screen. Confirmed on both Ubuntu 20.04 and 21.04.

It is possible to fix it by switching back to 100% scaling and then set 150% again (every time you log in). Or, probably, have it as a startup script which I could not figure yet.

Using Wayland is not an option for me because of reasons: lack of support from certain software such as IntelliJ IDEA so everything is blurry there with scaling enabled plus a couple of other issues.

Are there any workarounds for this issue?

Related bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1878282 (and few others are linked there as well)

One possible workaround is:

- make a file such as `~/Autostart/fractional_scaling.sh` and make it executable using `chmod a+x ~/Autostart/fractional_scaling.sh`

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter experimental-features "['scale-monitor-framebuffer']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 1.5
```

- go to Startup Application program
- make an entry for `~/Autostart/fractional_scaling.sh` there

log out, log in again and there is no stuck cursor anymore. HOWEVER, there is a small problem - not everything scales. For example, the "Do Not Disturb" icon is smaller than expected like it is still 100% and not 150%.

Comment: When you say cursor, are you talking about the capital “I” bar cursor used to input text? I (also) see this sometimes with standard 200% scaling and XOrg.

Comment: Does this go away if you restart gnome-shell using Ctrl+F2, r ?

Comment: @PJSingh I have added an example to the post ( https://imgur.com/a/nhzhaSb )

Comment: @PJSingh if I switch to Ctrl+F2 then Ctrl+F1 and log in again, the cursor will still be stuck, just at a different position.

Comment: I see your screen shot. In my case, I don't see a mouse pointer; instead I see a vertical "insert" cursor, like you would see in a text editor. However I suspect these are the same bug. Also, I mistyped my second question: I meant to ask, if you type Alt+F2 to launch the "Run a Command" dialog, and then if you type "r" and press Enter, to restart GNOME shell, does this resolve your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turned out that GDM was working on Wayland and that was causing troubles with XOrg sessions.

All I needed to do was

- `sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf`
- uncomment `WaylandEnable=false` (remove `#`)
- `sudo service gdm restart`

after that, fractional scaling produces no second stuck cursor on the screen.

Comment: I'm having similar issue, but when I opened custom.conf it waylandenable=false was already commented out. How should I fix this dead cursor issue?

Comment: @Mijir In my case, I just removed the comment (`#`) and it started working without the second cursor. Hopefully, anything else won't break.

Comment: thanks, fixed the comment. did not realize that it was that wrong :)